# What is DAGScheduler.messageProcessingTime?

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, emr

Can some point me where I can find the descriptions for the metrics I get from spark sink ?

Answer (score 2):

This is timer that tracks the time to process messages in the DAGScheduler's event loop

Note that this seems to include all kinds of events (JobSubmitted, JobCancelled, etc.)

It was introduced by [SPARK-8344](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8344) to help troubleshoot issue and delays in DAGScheduler's event loop. At least as far as I can understand.

I was hoping to be able to use it for payload processing time but that does not seem to be the correct metric for that.